Docker Compose bind mount issue on Windows: path conversion problem with network directory
Problem:
In a docker-compose.yaml file, I'm trying to mount a network directory using a bind mount:
      - type: bind
        source: T:/Folder/Subfolder
        target: /code/data-pipelines/T:/

However, when I run docker-compose up, I get an error:
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /run/desktop/mnt/host/uC/de-xy-00-00/Folder/Subfolder

The issue is that Docker Compose is converting the Windows path to a Unix-style path, which is not what I want.
Question:
How can I mount a Windows network directory using a bind mount in Docker Compose without Docker Compose converting the path?
